# handling external events in a cluster environment

Tags: java, java-ee, cluster

I have an app written with JSF and Spring using JPA+Hibernate which is running on a Glassfish4 server.
Right now I have an Observer pattern which is listening for some Postgresql events. Let`s say that on very insert in some table my listener is triggered.

Everything is OK now because I have only one server but I want to migrate to a cluster (4 nodes) setup, so there will be a problem because when an row will be inserted my trigger will be fired 4 times.

What is the common approach when you have to deal with this kind of things ?

I was thinking to keep a database table and when an event appears to check if the event id is not already in the table, but I think here I will have some concurrency issues and I`ll  have some rolled back transactions.

Any idea how I can elegantly deal with this ?

Comment: Is this application also the generator/publisher of these records/events? Or is that part of a different application? Do you have control over the publisher/generator? Are the records created purely to emit an event, or do they have intrinsic value besides invoking an action somewhere else in your system?

Comment: No, the generator is a PBX system. I have to know when a phone call was finished (that is the trigger) in order to start creating some permission for the users to see that call (users from my java app).

Comment: RE:my trigger will be fired 4 times - I'm not entirely clear on the concern here: if you have 4 separate VMs, connected to the same DB, won't you want the notification to be available in all 4 VMs?

Comment: No I do not, as the first VM that is triggered has to process that event and save the result in DB. The remaining vm`s should just ignore it.